# Handling a Save vs. a Submit button group on a form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I have a simple React Native Formik form with 2 buttons: Submit and Save.

I am trying to get the form to perform 2 separate actions depending on which button is used. All I need is to be able to determine in handleSubmit() which button was clicked on.

**Handle Submit**

```
const handleSubmit = (formData) => {
    //if Submit button event
    console.log(formData);

    //if Save button event
    console.log(formData)
};
```

**Formik form**

```
<Formik initialValues={{ email: "" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
        <View>
            <AppFormField
                onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
                value={values.email}
            />
            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Save" />
        </View>
    )}
</Formik>;
```

So far I tried using a state hook to change a variable that is set to which type of button is clicked, but I can't pass this variable to the handleSubmit().

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/214#issuecomment-443108973) help?

Comment: This is a great resource @NoobLife, but I can't make it work. The code samples are React JS and being new to React in general, I can't seem to apply their workaround to my React Native code.

Comment: If you add what you have tried, I could take a look at it.